# 80s anime in which a female looking cyborg doesn't want to be destroyed in a waste disposal

Tags: story-identification, anime

This female cyborg was trapped in a waste deposit, she was protecting what appears to be her child. She doesn't want to be destroyed/recycled. She wanted to live.

This female robot was originally a human but she wanted to get a robot body. After the transformation she couldn't afford the all the payments; that is the reason of why she's going to be recycled.

This is the only scene from that anime that I remember, it was a very sad and dark scene that impacted me so much when I was a child. I saw this only once in the 80s.

The animation style and characters design are similar to *[Galaxy Express 999](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQr-fnhGUes)*.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Can you remember anything about the visual style - how cartoony/naturalistic it looked, any other anime it might have looked like, etc.?

Comment: yep, the animation style is similar to "express 999".

Comment: And you're positive it's -not- Galaxy Express 999? That does, after all, have people with mechanical bodies and lots of tragedy.

Comment: There is a 1981 sequel movie "Adieu Galaxy Express 999" (two years after the events in Galaxy Express 999) where the boy (Tetsuro) meets Queen Prometheum, a blonde queen who looks very much like Maetel. This film is available in youtube.

Comment: I saw both movies, but the scene I'm looking for is not in them. I have also seen  the episodes from the original series without any luck.

Comment: Your description makes me think of [Gunnm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_Alita). There was several storylines though, so I may be mixing up different scenes, haven't read it in a long while.